# Display Partial domain path

Tags: php, javascript, html

**I'm not really sure how to word this, so i wasn't able to do much research before posting, so if the answer already exists i'm sorry and please post the link to the answer. Thanks.**

I have a file path like the one below.

```
http://www.green-panda.com/usd309bands/studentAccess/account.php
```

Does a way exist that I could make this appear as what is below so it doesn't reveal the full file paths?

```
http://www.green-panda.com/usd309bands/account.php
```

Eventually once this project is complete it will just be

```
http://www.usd309bands.org/account.php
```

Any ideas or previous answers that could help me with this? I know it is possible because i've seen it done before. Just never actually made it work. Anything with HTML, Javascript, or PHP will work.

Comment: This is called .htaccess redirect

Comment: Great. I've never had any luck doing anything with .htaccess

Comment: @sabof — No, it isn't. You can (assuming the web server is apache) do it with a **rewrite**, but that is better placed in a standard apache config than in a `.htaccess`.

Comment: @Quentin a `URL rewrite` ?

Comment: I meant rewrite. Would the Apache config still be the best option with multiple sites per server?

Comment: or a PHP controller that routes URL's to files !

Comment: @sabof — Yes. Especially if you have one virtual host per config file (which is how most servers I've used in recent years are set up).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your webserver. Assuming you are using Apache (since it is pretty common), [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) `/usd309bands/` to `/var/www/or/wherever/usd309bands/studentAccess/`.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out, It's a really good article I was able to find once @sabof pointed out the url rewrite name in the comments of the answer.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/